# How to include files in particular media?

Tags: install4j

There are about 30 media in our project. Now we have to add extra files to one of the media. AFAIU the proper way is to create a separate file set and disable it in *all other* media. But does exist an opposite (simple) way to *enable* the file set in a particular media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6.1 this is not possible, it's planned for a future version.